# Getting 2 returns instead of 1 in tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, mocking

I'm writing test using double/stub, and i want to return me a fake value, but instead i'm getting and fake value and real value. Here is my controller and spec files, model has nothing in it. Any ideas what am i doing wrong? My guess is i'm doing it completely wrong. P.s. i'm kinda new to spec and mock/stub things

controller:

```
def destroy
    uri = URI('example.com')
    request_params = {'requestId' => @session.id, 
      'merchantId' => MERCHANTID, 
      'locale' => LOCALE, 
      'partnerId' => PARTNERID, 
      'sessionId' => params[:id]
    }

   Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port, :use_ssl => uri.scheme == 'https') do |http|
      request = Net::HTTP::Post.new uri.request_uri
      request.set_form_data(request_params)
      #request.content_type = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      response = http.request request # Net::HTTPResponse object
      json = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(response.body)
      puts '<<<<<<<<<'
      puts json
      if json['expireSessionRes']['isError'] == false
        render :json => {:status => 'ok', :message => 'logged out'}
      else
        render :json => {:status => 'failed', :message => 'logout failed'}
      end
    end
```

spec file:

```
it "should correctly return isError false if logout was sucessful" do
    SID = "123"
    @data3 = {:id => SID}  
    delete :destroy, default_rest_params.merge(@data3)
    response = double('http.request')
    response.stub!(:body => '{"expireSessionRes"=>{"requestId"=>"72", "sessionId"=>"123", "isError"=>false, "desc"=>""}}')
    puts response.body


  end
```

receiving:

```
{"expireSessionRes"=>{"requestId"=>"94", "isError"=>true, "desc"=>"Session exipred", "errorCode"=>"-10011"}}
{"expireSessionRes"=>{"requestId"=>"72", "sessionId"=>"123", "isError"=>false, "desc"=>""}}
```

first comes from controller 
second from stub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the thing with mocking and stubbing is, you have to hook your mock objects up to your real code somehow... the `double('http.request')` bit just creates a mock object called "http.request", it doesn't make `http.request` return this object.

What you need to do is stub the `request` method to return the mock response. But it's going to be pretty difficult to inject a mock, because you don't have access to the `http` object in the block from your tests.

Difficulty testing code is often a good sign that you need to refactor your code.

The simplest thing would be to replace the whole `Net::HTTP.start` thing with a single line

```
response = Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, request_params)
```

and then you can test it by doing

```
remote_response = double('remote_response', body: '...')
Net::HTTP.stub(:post_form).and_return(remote_response)

delete :destroy, ...

response.should whatever
```

(I assume you're in a controller spec and you're going to need the `response` object that RSpec provides, so your mock can't be stored in a variable called `response`).

But that is just glossing over the more important point that you should be extracting your remote service interaction out into a dedicated class and testing that separately, it doesn't belong in the controller.

Hope that helps!